# jQuery parse json and get element, getting undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a text and a button:

```
<div id="divtest"> <h1> Bla </h1> </div>
<button id="dugme1"> dugme </button>
```

When the user clicks the button, this script is called:

```
$("#dugme1").click(function(){

    $.get("http://mypath/PP/cfcs/remote.cfc", {
        method: 'listProjects',
        returnformat: 'json'
    },function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var t = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(t.PMNAME);
    })

    });
```

So I get this as a response in the console when I click a button:

```
[{"PNAME":"JumpingBunny","ANAME":"Nikola","PID":1,"PMNAME":"Marko"},{"PNAME":"WorkerLogger","ANAME":"Ivan","PID":2,"PMNAME":""},{"PNAME":"TimeStampter","ANAME":"Kevin","PID":3,"PMNAME":"Bart"},{"PNAME":"BugFixer2","ANAME":"Ivan","PID":4,"PMNAME":"Clark"},{"PNAME":"EditorS","ANAME":"Homer","PID":5,"PMNAME":"Bruce"}]
```

But **I want the alert to show me the value of PNAME**. But I get undefined when I click the button.

What am I doing wrong ?
This is the developer console:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `t` is an array, you have to use index like:

```
t[0].PMNAME
```

To print all `PMNAME` you can use `forEach()` on the array:

```js
var t = [{"PNAME":"JumpingBunny","ANAME":"Nikola","PID":1,"PMNAME":"Marko"},{"PNAME":"WorkerLogger","ANAME":"Ivan","PID":2,"PMNAME":""},{"PNAME":"TimeStampter","ANAME":"Kevin","PID":3,"PMNAME":"Bart"},{"PNAME":"BugFixer2","ANAME":"Ivan","PID":4,"PMNAME":"Clark"},{"PNAME":"EditorS","ANAME":"Homer","PID":5,"PMNAME":"Bruce"}];

t.forEach(function(i){
  console.log(i.PNAME)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var obj = [{"PNAME":"JumpingBunny","ANAME":"Nikola","PID":1,"PMNAME":"Marko"},{"PNAME":"WorkerLogger","ANAME":"Ivan","PID":2,"PMNAME":""},{"PNAME":"TimeStampter","ANAME":"Kevin","PID":3,"PMNAME":"Bart"},{"PNAME":"BugFixer2","ANAME":"Ivan","PID":4,"PMNAME":"Clark"},{"PNAME":"EditorS","ANAME":"Homer","PID":5,"PMNAME":"Bruce"}];

console.log( obj[0].PNAME );
```

```js
var obj = [{"PNAME":"JumpingBunny","ANAME":"Nikola","PID":1,"PMNAME":"Marko"},{"PNAME":"WorkerLogger","ANAME":"Ivan","PID":2,"PMNAME":""},{"PNAME":"TimeStampter","ANAME":"Kevin","PID":3,"PMNAME":"Bart"},{"PNAME":"BugFixer2","ANAME":"Ivan","PID":4,"PMNAME":"Clark"},{"PNAME":"EditorS","ANAME":"Homer","PID":5,"PMNAME":"Bruce"}];

console.log( obj[0].PNAME );
```

**Explanation:** As you are having an array of object so you have to specify the index and key to access any element.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` from `http://mypath/PP/cfcs/remote.cfc` is stringified array of objects so you need to access the object using its array `index` value. So, when you do

```
var t = JSON.parse(data);
alert(t.PMNAME);
```

The value of `t` is an array so you probably need to loop through `t` to get all the object or use the `index` value `0,1, ..., t.length-1` to get the specific object.

Thus, you need to do `alert(t[0].PMNAME);`

Answer (score 0):

Array of object is returned. So to get a first element of array you should use:

```
alert(t[0].PMNAME);
```